# How to pass value of an HTML element to 'ajax' option during datatable initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have created a datatable and have given it an ajax URL for server processing. I have an additional requirement now where I need to update the contents of datatable depending on the value selected from an HTML dropdown element.

I don't know how to grab the selected value of an HTML dropdown and pass it to datatable so it can be used in AJAX server request.

Basically, I want the datatable to be instantly updated with new data when a user selects a value from the dropdown.

I tried making "data" field as function but all I am able to do in that function is send a key value pair field in the request. I could not retrieve the value of HTML select in the data function.

I tried this -

```
var table = $('#datatable8').DataTable({
"dom": 'T<"clear">lrBtip',
"ajax": {
"url": ajaxURL,
"data": {
  "searchType": $('#selectdays').val()
  }
},
"order": [[2, 'asc']],
"columns": dtcols,
"buttons": [
{
  text: 'Download',
  id: 'downloadbutton',
  className: 'btn ink-reaction btn-flat table-button',
  action: function() {
    var type = $('#selectdays').val();
    location.href = '/admin/reports/lease/'+type;
  }
}
],
"serverSide": true,
"processing": true,
"searching": true,
"stateSave": true,
"paging": true,
"language": {
"lengthMenu": '_MENU_ entries per page',
"search": '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>',
"paginate": {
  "previous": '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
  "next": '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
}
},
"createdRow": function(row, data) {
//attach site id to a row so we can reference it when clicking 
buttons etc
$(row).attr('data-siteid', data["siteid"]);

if(data["deactivatedat"]) {
  $(row).find('.btn.disable-asset').removeClass('btn- 
flat').addClass('btn-danger').removeClass('disable- 
asset').addClass('enable-asset').text('RE-ENABLE');
}
}
});
```

This is my HTML dropdown element:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectdays">
<option value="1">Please Select</option>
<option value="2">30 Days Report</option>
<option value="3">60 Days Report</option>
<option value="0">90 Days Report</option>
</select>
```

But, line `"searchType": $('#selectdays').val()` does not create anything in the request.

Comment: Check out the second example on DataTables' [ajax.data page](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data).

Comment: I just tried but nothing came in the request object.

Comment: ```"data": function ( d )
    {d.extra_search = $('#selectdays').val();
     }```


This does not show up in the request object

Comment: What server-side language are you using? Are you checking for a GET or POST variable on the server? Default is GET unless you specify POST. Edit: Just noticed, too, the `removeClass` and `addClass` calls are repeated on the same element - just so you know, you can use `removeClass('btn-flat disable-asset')` (just separate classes with a space) to remove both at one time.

Comment: Yes, I am only checking for GET. I am using Node(Express).

Comment: @mark.hch Yeah I just realized for the removeClass. Thanks for that.

Comment: I feel I am missing something very small here and its irritating me now

Comment: I copied your code exactly as posted in the original question (and defined the `ajaxURL` and `dtcols` variables), and it seems to work with PHP as the backend (checking for `$_GET['searchType']`). If you're not seeing it in Express under `req.query.searchType`, then I'm at a loss. Edit: I used jQuery 1.11.1, and DataTables 1.10.16, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @mark.hch Can you share your code with PHP?

Comment: Sure - I'm not familiar with good online PHP playgrounds that allow multiple files and sharing without paying - so I bundled the index.php and server.php file in one file, and put it on pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/raw/Va0dBN0t. If you use it locally, you'll just want to separate it into the two files, and change the paths to jQuery and DataTables.

Comment: @mark.hch Thanks Mark